# Python -- Obtaining text from newspaper website

Tags: html, python-2.7

I took up a pet-project:
To obtain the "English text" from a newspaper website and dump it into a file.
Through my research, I have been introduced to interesting modules like bs4, re, etc
My current script makes use of bs4. Scripting language: Python(2.7). Please have a look.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

from_the_web = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/tp-national/") #This is a file-object
soup = BeautifulSoup(from_the_web.read(),'html.parser')

myFile = open('Nag.txt','w')
myFile.truncate()
myFile.write("These are the results from thehindu.com:\n\n")

failures = 0
for line in soup.get_text():
    try:
        myFile.write(line)
    except:
        failures += 1

print "Successfully written lines with %d failures" %(failures)
myFile.close()

print "Done"
```

I have been able to extract all of the text, however, a lot of non-English text was also dumped into my file (Nag.txt). Here is a sample:

```
(function (w, d, u) {
w.readyQ = [];
w.bindReadyQ = [];
function p(x, y) {
if (x == "ready") {
w.bindReadyQ.push(y);
} else {
w.readyQ.push(x);
}
};
var a = {ready: p, bind: p};
w.$ = w.jQuery = function (f) {
if (f === d || f === u) {
return a
} else {
p(f)
}
}
})(window, document)
```

Is this some other scripting language that was coupled with HTML? If so, please give suggestions on how to obtain pure English-text from the website.

Comment: Please post contents of Nag.txt

Comment: My friend, the content is so much, stackoverflow says I have exceeded the word limit. I would suggest you run the above python code to see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use BeautifulSoup to filter out the `<script>` tags. For example,

```
soup.find_all("div")
```